# I created a MongoDB user with full credentials yet authentication fails when trying to connect to a db using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Im using MongoDB server version:4.0.6 and Mongoose version 5.4.18. I have created the following MongoDB user:

```
"_id" : "admin.matt",
"user" : "matt",
"db" : "admin",
"roles" : [
        {
                "role" : "readWrite",
                "db" : "user-data"
        },
        {
                "role" : "userAdminAnyDatabase",
                "db" : "admin"
        },
        {
                "role" : "readWrite",
                "db" : "admin"
        },
        {
                "role" : "dbAdminAnyDatabase",
                "db" : "admin"
        },
        {
                "role" : "readWriteAnyDatabase",
                "db" : "admin"
        }
],
"mechanisms" : [
        "SCRAM-SHA-1",
        "SCRAM-SHA-256"
]
```

I am trying to connect using the following mongoose command:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://matt:passwordexample!@localhost:27017/user-data', {useNewUrlParser: true});
```

It replies with **MongoError: Authentication failed.**

I have tried multiple connection formats and nothing as worked.  Is my user credentials not set up correctly?  Thank you.

and this is my package.json.  Do I need MongoDB here if I have mongoose?

```
"dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "express-handlebars": "^3.0.2",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "express-validator": "^5.3.1",
    "forever": "^0.15.3",
    "mongoose": "^5.4.18",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.10",
    "path": "^0.12.7"
  },
```

Comment: which version of mongoDB you are using?

Comment: @ykit9 I'm using MongoDB server version 4.0.6  I just realized it's not listed as a dependency though, is that an issue?

Comment: Change the options to `{ useNewUrlParser: true, authSource: "admin" }` and also try `authSource: "user-data"` for what it's worth. The default place *should* be `admin` and it *looks like* that is what you did, but try both just to be sure. You should also note that the `readWriteAnyDatabase` basically overrides any "lesser" privilege you have assigned. So you probably want to edit that out of the account your application ends up using.

Answer (score 0):

If the username or password includes the at sign @, colon :, slash /, or the percent sign % character use percent encoding.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#urioption.authSource

Or you can try this,

```
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "matt",
    pwd: "passwordexample!",
    roles: [ { role: "root", db: "admin" } ]
  }
)
```

Comment: My password only contains an exclamation point, no other special characters. Are my current user credentials incorrect? Do I need a 'root' rule?

Comment: You actually need to create one more user for user-data database. Like this `use user-data db.createUser( { user: "matt", pwd: "passwordexample!", roles:[{role: "userAdmin" , db:"user-data"}]})`

Comment: the "anydatabases" rules dont do that for me, basically? I have to create a user in user-data specifically?

Comment: I now have a user with _id: "user-data.matt" and that user has role: userAdmin in db "user-data" and I'm still getting an authentication error.

Answer (score 0):

You did not specified the authSource in your connection string:
`mongodb://matt:passwordexample!@localhost:27017/user-data?authSource=admin`.

Comment: omg that was it.......... -_- thank you!! why does this: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html not say that at all?